# php html form manipulation

Tags: php

i need documentation of php, mysql, jQuery, ajax, html form manipulation. i study php, and i want to make large ordering form.
for example:

> http://www.formstack.com/online-order-form.html

i want to make filters

> http://www.pugetsystems.com/configure.php?app_type=h

how can i do this? is there any documentation about this?

```
DON'T NEED A CODE, I NEED DOCUMENTATION!!!
```

Comment: Sorry @Mike, there are not even nearly enough specifics. Your question is supposed to show attempted work so that users can help you with problems. No one wants to write the code for you.

Comment: i dont need a code, i need good tutorials and documentation :)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is way too broad to fit on Stack Overflow as a single question. There are tones of tutorials out on the web about these pieces of technology, pick one, start to read, and when you're stumped, come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://www.php.net/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/
- http://docs.jquery.com/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0):

You should start with simple HTML form and JavaScript validation (for example if you are going to use jQuery I suggest to try jQuery Tools).

First you check everything with Javascript on the client side and then when everything is set, you can user jQuery to post the form to the server (some PHP file) and put it into the DB.